# comparing lists python Tron game

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

I am writing code for a project in school and am trying to recreate Tron in Python. I have code that inserts the bikes current position into a list named self.body2 and then compare it to the current position of the other bike named self.pos . Through error testing I managed to figure out that the problem is probably in the second if statement because self.pos and x are updating properly but the program never prints "yes".

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

(Some code from my project, assuming that self.angle = "u" for both bikes)

```
def twoPlayer(self):
    while self.alive == True and self.alive2 == True:
        self.drawSnake()
        self.runGame()
        self.runGame2()
        self.theWindow.after(100)
        self.theWindow.update_idletasks()
        self.theWindow.update()

def runGame(self):
    self.body.insert(0,list(self.pos))

    if self.angle == "u":
        self.pos[1] -= 10
        self.pos[3] -= 10

def runGame2(self):
    self.body2.insert(0,list(self.pos2))

    if self.angle2 == "u":
        self.pos2[1] -= 10
        self.pos2[3] -= 10

    for x in self.body:
        if self.pos2 == x:
            print("yes")
            self.alive2 = False
    for x in self.body2:
        if self.pos2 == x:
            self.alive2 = False
```

Comment: can you post a briefer code? It will help others to understand the problem clearly.

Comment: You need to post enough code that we can run it and see what the problem is.

Comment: It seems that you move by steps of 10. In that case, paths might cross without having exactly overlapping coordinates. Maybe try using `if abs(self.pos2[i] - x[i]) <= 5:` with `i` the coordinate you want to check, instead of `if self.pos2 == x:`